# what is $|x|$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Tags: general-topology, notation

What is |x| given by in dimension n? 
What is |x| when x lies in the set of real numbers to the power n. 
This is needed in order to find the laplacian of u when u is equal to an equation involving |x|.
What is $|x|$ when $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$

Comment: I don't mean to discourage you and I hope I'm wrong, but if you need to ask this, you need to review some material before tackling whatever it is that you're tackling. Take this comment as the best of two evils.

Answer (score 2):

if $x=(x_1,x_2,...x_n)$ is an element of
$R^n$ then you can take the Euclidian norm given by
$|x|=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+...x_n^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

What is typically meant is the frobenius norm $|x|=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}$

Answer (score 1):

What $|x|$ means in a general normed space is the norm of $x$, where a norm is a function from $X\times X\to \Bbb R$. The most typical norm in $\Bbb R^n$ is the euclidean norm where
$$|x|=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}$$
This is however not all the norms possible to concieve, however many norms are equivalent to it.

Answer (score 1):

The three are equivalent and you can use any of them:

$|x|= \sqrt{ x_1^2 + \cdots x_n^2}$,

$|x|= \max\{|x_1|, \cdots, |x_n|\}$,

$ |x|= |x_1|+ \cdots+ |x_n|$.

Comment: That's great. I have to put $u=w\left(\frac{|x|}{t^(1/2)}\right)t^{\frac{1}{1-p}}$, $(x,t) \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \times [0,T]$ into $u_{t} - \Delta u = u|u|^{p-1}$ but cannot get an answer that works.